# Operación con dos números con while y try

Tags: python

debo estoy haciendo esto: desde la consola debo ingresar dos numeros. Por ejemplo a/b, b/a. Si a=0 y b diferente de cero, entonces debe pedir que ingrese a diferente de cero. Si b=0 y a diferente de cero, entonces debe pedir que ingrese b diferente de cero. Si ahora, se ingresa un string en a, debe pedir que ingrese un nuevo número que sea dfierente de cero y que sea numero. Lomismo para cuando se ignresa un string en b.

Debo intentar con while y try. Dejo mi programación. Muchas Gracias!

```
a= input('ingrese el primer número')
b=input('ingrese el segundo número')

while type(a)!= int and type(b)!=int:
  try: 
    a=int(a)
    b=int(b)
    print('la división entre los dos números es:',a/b, 'también:',b/a)
  except:
    print('no se puede divir para cero porque a=0')
    if type(a)==int and type(b)!=int:
      b=input('ingrese nuevamente')
    elif type(b)==int and type(a)!=int:
      a=input('ingrese nuevamente')
```

Answer (score 1):

Sale mejor hacer una función de entrada de datos donde controlas las posibilidades. La única manera de salir de la función es que el `if` sea válido: con cualquier entero (si `cero=True`) o que el valor sea un entero distinto de cero (si `cero=False`). De lo contrario quedará atrapado por el ciclo infinito del `while`.

```py
def pedir_entero(msg, cero=True):
    while True:
        try:
            v = int(input(msg))
            if cero or (v != 0):
                return v
            else:
                print("El valor no puede ser cero, reintente")
        except:
            print("El valor introducido no es correcto, reintente")

# ### Programa principal ###
x = pedir_entero('Ingrese el primer numero: ' ) # permite 0
y = pedir_entero('Ingrese el segundo numero: ', False) # no permite 0
print(f'Los valores ingresados fueron: ({x}, {y})')
```

Comment: Ya me salió. Mil gracias!